# Bibliography: what is the correct way to setup and invoke the category 'electronic'

Tags: context

**Short question:**

What is the correct way to setup and invoke the bibliography mecanism in context, to use, for example, the category *electronic*?

**Long question:**

Looking at context documentations and source code, it says that for electronic category we have:

- Required fields: title
- Optional fields: address, author, howpublished, month, note, organization, url, year, doi

In this way, for example, consider the following code:

```
\startbuffer[example]
@ELECTRONIC {example,
    title = "One title",
    url = "http://www.example.org",
}
\stopbuffer

\usebtxdefinitions[aps]

\definebtxdataset[basic]
\usebtxdataset[basic][example.buffer]
\definebtxrendering
    [basic]
    [aps]
    [dataset=basic]

\setupbtx[dataset=basic]
\nocite[example]

\starttext
\placelistofpublications[basic]
\stoptext
```

When rendered, it produces this awful output:

[image: Output from the code above]

so, to me, this is an errouneous output once only title and url should be rendered. Then here is my question, how is the correct way to use this category, what am I missing?

PS.:

If I add this code:

```
\startsetups btx:aps:list:electronic
    \btxdoif {author} {
        \texdefinition{btx:aps:author}
    }
    \texdefinition{btx:aps:title}
    \texdefinition{btx:aps:organization-if-not-author}
    \btxdoif {howpublished} {
        \texdefinition{btx:aps:doi-url} {\btxspace\btxflush{howpublished}}
    }
    \btxdoif {year} {
        \btxleftparenthesis
        \texdefinition{btx:aps:year}
        \btxrightparenthesis
    }
    \texdefinition{btx:aps:note}
\stopsetups
```

I've got the correct output:

[image: correct output]

But it does not seem correct to me that I need to change such definitions

Comment: You should report this on the [ConTeXt mailing list](https://mailman.ntg.nl/mailman/listinfo/ntg-context) because the authors of the module aren't on this site.